# Есть приложение Django на VDS, которое работает, но при подключении .DLL возникает ошибка 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

Tags: python, django, dll, python-3.10, pythonnet

Не могу устранить ошибку:

> module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

VDS Ubuntu22+Apache2 +Python3.10.9+ Django 4, 1, 5 +ip и доменное имя, все работает нормально, но мне нужно подключить dll (.net7.0)(`dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.22.04-x64 --self-contained`)- если вы подключаетесь к VDS через клиент Openssh, то .dll подключится в среде python3, которая там есть, но при загрузке страницы возникает ошибка

> module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

единственное отличие, которое я заметил, заключается в том, что сайт выдает `Python.version=3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [ GCC 11.3.0]`, (`import sys; sys.version`) , когда я нахожусь в клиенте Openssh, он пишет `3.10.9 (main, Jan 24 2023, 10:16:41) [GCC 11.3.0]`, может быть, это какая-то причина?

вот что я имею за Traceback загрузки сайта :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djangoexample4/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/djangoexample4/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoexample4/mainapp/views.py", line 135, in index
    clr.AddReference('/home/djangoexample4/btclinux2/MyLibraryName/bin/Debug/net7.0/ubuntu.22.04-x64/MyLibraryName.dll')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
```

если через openSSH client подключатся к VDS, то ни какой ошибки уже почемуто нет:

```
# monop -r /home/djangoexample4/btclinux2/MyLibraryName/bin/Debug/net7.0/ubuntu.22.04-x64/MyLibraryName.dll

Assembly Information:
MyLibraryName
Version=1.0.0.0
Culture=neutral
PublicKeyToken=null
MyLibraryName.Class1
Total: 1 types.
```

исходный C# (класс проекта classlib , созданного на vds dotnet-ом, и потом dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.22.04-x64 --self-contained, чтобы появился наш dll):

```cs
namespace MyLibraryName
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int method1()
        {
            return 777;
        }
    }
}
```

вот это при обращении через консоль на этом VDS:

```
# python3
>>> import clr
>>> clr.AddReference('/home/djangoexample4/btclinux2/MyLibraryName/bin/Debug/net7.0/ubuntu.22.04-x64/MyLibraryName.dll')
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x7f9c3b928640>
>>> from MyLibraryName import Class1
>>> variable = Class1().method1()
>>> print(variable)
777
```

вот это тоже делал:

```sh
pip uninstall clr
pip uninstall pythonnet
pip install pythonnet
```

функция `dir()` возвращает список имён, определяемых объектом:

dir(clr) через openSSH client:

```
['AddReference', 'FindAssembly', 'GetClrType', 'ListAssemblies', '__class__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_add_pending_namespaces', '_available_namespaces', '_extras', '_load_clr_module', 'clrmethod', 'clrproperty', 'getPreload', 'loader', 'setPreload']
```

dir(clr) при загрузке страницы:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'load']
```

Comment: Как вы себе представляете, чтобы dll работал на vds с Ubuntu?

Comment: все там работает , я ж выше об этом писал через консоль подключаюсь к VDS в среде пайтон там все читается, выше в описании пример работы

Comment: Определённо стоит сперва разобраться, откуда взялись две разные версии питона. Как вы установили и настроили сайт? Он у вас через какой-нибудь mod_wsgi работает или как?

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать сделать `print(clr)` чтобы сравнить, какой модуль импортируется в консоли, а какой в сайте

Comment: lib mod_wsgi для apache2, с нуля сейчас удалил весь python3.10, ставлю так https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-python-3-10-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/ но версию 3.10.9, пока в процессе Install Python 3.10 – Manual Method

Comment: Переставил python, но ошибка таже
AttributeError at /
module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: #########
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
Exception Location: /home/djangoexample4/mainapp/views.py, line 44, in index
Raised during: mainapp.views.index
Python Executable: /home/djangoexample4/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.10.9
. . .
Server time: Wed, 25 Jan 2023 20:03:54 +0300 ( теперь там и там версия 3.10.9)

Comment: все теже:
 /env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner
/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 197, in _get_response
может быть что то связанно с  django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler ?

Comment: wsgi.py :
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoexample4.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()

Comment: функция dir() возвращает список имён, определяемых объектом
в консоли:
dir(clr):['AddReference', 'FindAssembly', 'GetClrType', 'ListAssemblies', '__class__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_add_pending_namespaces', '_available_namespaces', '_extras', '_load_clr_module', 'clrmethod', 'clrproperty', 'getPreload', 'loader', 'setPreload']
в загрузке страницы:
dir(clr):['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'load']
 и что с этим делать?

Comment: Если посмотреть список импортированных модулей, то<module 'clr' from 'unknown'> нет, смотрел вот так: 
    import sys
    modulenames = set(sys.modules) & set(globals())
    allmodules = [sys.modules[name] for name in modulenames], тоесть он чеготось вообще неподгружается при загрузке страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` в `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/youdomain.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 . . .
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

И это все заработало!